# Css Hover Selector should select complete row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that the complete row is selected and not just an element in that row. Also the selection should not care about paddings and margins and just take the full width and the size of the biggest element for all elements.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t3uz2r52/1/
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Disc_Plain_red.svg/460px-Disc_Plain_red.svg.png" class="img-responsive status">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 myimg">
            <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KlULoQj3nao/maxresdefault.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 description">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
                aliquyam erat,
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.row :hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: `.row:hover {...` <- no space to select the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your CSS to

```
.row:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Thereby you can assign `:hover` selector to entire row. Read more about [Pseudo-class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Pseudo-classes_selectors).

Here is you updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3uz2r52/3/).

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have a space before `:hover` that it applies to child elements instead of the `.row` element.

```
.row:hover {   // There should be no space before :hover
  background-color: green;
}
```